# Error "/run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory" - but not Grub related

Tags: linux, lvm

All LVM commands give me the error `/run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory`. I Googled this error and found only postings related to Grub and Grub-install.

wish to get rid of those errors

```
# pvs
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad: No such file or directory. Falling back to internal scanning.
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  PV         VG      Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/vdb1  vdatavg lvm2 a--  16.00g 6.00g
```

Comment: Are you in a chrooted environment?

Comment: I am. What should I do?

Answer (score 20):

If you are using lvm and systemd do:

```
systemctl enable lvm2-lvmetad.service
systemctl enable lvm2-lvmetad.socket
systemctl start lvm2-lvmetad.service
systemctl start lvm2-lvmetad.socket
```

BTW this is grub related as well. I think grub gets kernel parameter **root** from /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket.

Wasn't patient to test all this in detail as it worked out to function. Please someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Edit: This is only relevant for systems using systemd for init. If you are on older ubuntu you mnight be using upstart instead and on other systems openrc.

Comment: I did all those commands, none gave me any error. But when I have chrooted and try to update my grub using `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`, it still returns me the error `/run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 uses systemd now

Comment: "running in chroot, ignoring request"

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you're running Linux, in `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` set:

```
use_lvmetad = 0
```

Stop LVM prior to doing that: `/etc/init.d/lvm stop`. Make the change and restart LVM: `/etc/init.d/lvm start`.

**EDIT**: I realize there's no such file or directory on Linux Mint, hence neither on Debian nor Ubuntu, shall I deduce. If you don't have such a service, just reboot the computer.

**Hint**: add your operating system in the tag list.

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 I do have an `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`.